# Comparing spectral radii of two non-negative matrices

Tags: matrices, spectral-radius, nonnegative-matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ non-negative matrices with spectral radii $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$, respectively. Suppose that $A_{ij} \leq B_{ij}$ for all $i,j$. Then, $$\lambda_A \leq \lambda_B$$

I found this theorem in a paper, but the author did not provide proper reference on the proof. After searching in some texts, I only found the version for when $B$ is irreducible.

1. If this is true, could anyone kindly point me a reference on this theorem?
2. Please kindly suggest me a suitable book about matrix theory and spectral radius since I haven't read much about this topic.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: BTW, since you ask for references on the theory: The question's title is nearly identical to a paper by R. B. Bapat: "Comparing the Spectral Radii of Two Nonnegative Matrices". It is worth checking out the paper, its references, and this author's other work for other (IMO) interesting results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0\leqslant A_{ij}\leqslant B_{ij}$ for all $i,j$ then $$\sum_{i=1}^n |A_{ij}| \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n |B_{ij}| \text{ for all } j, $$
and hence $\|A\|_1\leqslant \|B\|_1$, where
$$
\|A\|_1 = \max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\sum_{i=1}^n |A_{ij}|.
$$
By monotonicity of the maps $A\mapsto A^k$ and $x\mapsto x^{1/k}$ it follows that $$\|A^k\|_1^{1/k}\leqslant\|B^k\|_1^{1/k}$$ for all $k>0$. Hence by Gelfand's formula
$$
\rho(A) = \lim_{k\to\infty}\|A^k\|_1^{1/k}\leqslant \lim_{k\to\infty}\|B^k\|_1^{1/k}=\rho(B),
$$
where $\rho(\cdot)$ denotes spectral radius.